# Drupal 7 views: Get NID in views using contextual filters

Tags: views, nodes

Does anybody know how to get the `nid` from a node using contextual filters or filter criteria in views

**WITHOUT** using "Get id from url"?  I was thinking about using PHP or getting it from a node-field.

My view is a block of comments that is to be placed together with a node. The comments needs to belong to the node and linked by node ID. In this case the "Get ID from url" wont work since the node itself is listed in another view.

It is a view-block (containing comments) inside of a node that is listed in a view.

Comment: I have added a bit more, does it make sense? :) @krister andersson

Comment: Do you use `views_get_view` in a template file to load and display your view?

Comment: I use the following to print the comments in the node template file

`<?php

$block = block_load('views', 'comments-block');      
$output = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));        
print $output; 
?> `

Would another print-method work better?

@krister andersson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are loading and displaying your view in the `node.tpl` or `node--<content-type>.tpl` file, you could supply the current node `nid` as an argument to your block view, then you can setup a contextual filter for `Content: Nid`. I would do something like this:

```
 // get view
 $view = views_get_view('YOUR_VIEW_NAME');
 // set display for view
 $view->set_display('YOUR_VIEW_BLOCK_NAME');
 // set current node nid as argument to view
 $view->set_arguments(array($node->nid));
 // execute view
 $view->execute();
 // render view
 print $view->render();
```

You could also try to use [`views_embed_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) which I think would be the preferred way to do this. It takes two parameters, `name` and `display_id`, any additional parameters will be passed as arguments to the view:

```
print views_embed_view('YOUR_VIEW_NAME', 'YOUR_VIEW_BLOCK_NAME', $node->nid);
```

I'm not sure that this helps, the question is a little vague=)

Comment: Im sorry if the question was badly formulated, but I like where the answer is going! I have used your code in the template-file of the node now, how to I let the "comments-view" to get the argument?

My current view-setup :

"View A"  :   Listing nodes

"Node A"  :   Is part of "View A" and has "View B" printed inside.

"View B"  :    Lists comments. Comments need to show based on the node ID so that the right comments show. This view is the one that needs to collect the argument. 



"View B" setup: Relationships: "Comment:Content" , "Cont.Filt:Comment:Nid"

Did this clarify the situation?

Comment: It's a little hard to answer without knowing exactly how you have setup your view. If you export the view and email me I can have a closer look.

Comment: If `View B` is an attached view you should be able to pass the `nid` by setting `Inherit contextual filters` to true under `Attachment Settings`.

Comment: Your code was all that was needed, it did the trick and saved me hours, thanks a million!