# Multiple nodes from a single content type?

Tags: nodes

I'm trying to create a single content type that displays data across multiple pages for a client. For example:

DOG content type with fields:

- List item
- Name (Title)
- Breed
- History (Body)
- Age
- Weight
- Height
- Previous Owner Name
- Previous Owner State
- Previous Owner Gender

and then I would I like these pages created automatically:

```
/dog/<name> (overview page that includes Name, Breed, History)
/dog/<name>/details (includes age, weight, height)
/dog/<name>/owner (includes previous owner name, state, gender)
```

Each page would have a submenu that links to the other pages. I can create the first overview page no problem, but how would I create the the second and third pages? Would I look at the URL pattern to find content matching the name?

Answer (score 2):

As fas as i understand the question your requirement is to display those content on different pages. So it is better to create a three different [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) displaying the required data.For example you can create first view name dog1 having field name , breed and history and a second view name dog2 having field age weight and height and so on. And also you add submenu of those two pages link.

Comment: I've only ever used Views to display content listings, so this is a fantastic idea. As I asked xurshid29, any advice for building out the contextual filter?

Comment: this may help you `http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/51426/14555`

Answer (score 1):

According to me one should create 3 different views and according to the requirement one can select the fields.
Like
let the first view be **dog1** having fields **Name, Breed, History**.
second view be **dog2** having fields **age, weight, height**.
third view be **dog3** having fields **previous owner name, state, gender**.

Answer (score 1):

you can create  thre diffrent views for your three pagess and
regarding the display of views and sub menu on a common page u can go for node pages structure just design a page and add varient to it ..!!
hope this would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can create views with contexual filters and create menu path like dog/%/details(or owner), pass argument from cont.filter or, second method, read about hook_menu and _to_arg() function..

Comment: Any advice for building the contextual filter? I've tried using the NID with "Raw value from URL" and "Use Path Alias". If I type in the NID in the Preview panel it shows up, but if I type in the final section of my aliased path it does not.

Comment: ok, i'll give you a quick example for dog/<name>/details: 1. Create page view, add menu link like dog/%/details; 2. Add desired fields (age, weight, height); 3. Add one contexual filter based on name field, and configure filter like this: Provide default value: Raw value from URl, Path component - 2, check Use path alias; This is main configs, otionally you can check Override title and create your own title

Comment: After that you will need to create menu links like dog/<nameOfDog>/details. The easiest way is to create with Views,. Just create block with views and from Rewrite results container check Output this field as a link, then build url like this dog/[TOKEN FOR NAME FIELD]/details. If you do not see your name field token then add that field and move it top and set Exclude from display;

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would prefer to solve this with tabs. JavaScript-based tabs are better for SEO because the entire node can be indexed at once. I also think that views adds unnecessary overhead if you use it to display only one node. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550534/how-to-display-node-fields-in-tabs for instructions.

Comment: Each of the tabs I'm building are pretty media intensive, so I'd just be worried about download size/time?

Comment: That's a legitimate concern. You could consider using a javascript lazy loader such as http://drupal.org/project/lazyloader, which only loads the image when needed. However I do not know how it combines with tabs, you would have to try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Node Embed](http://drupal.org/project/node_embed) it's used by [www.whitehouse.gov](http://www.whitehouse.gov/developers) and is cited

> Node Embed provides an input filter for CKEditor & FCKEditor integration allowing a content editor the ability to embed the rendering of nodes within the body/fields of another node.

Im not much of a programer but this seems to be a nice simple solution.

Best of luck!

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for, but it looks very helpful for other future projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using [Ctools Page Manager](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) + [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds). It's possible to build exactly what you have asked for using these 2 modules in combination: Page Manager to create the tabs and Display Suite to define the content display for each one. There's quite a lot to learn when using these modules but once you have become familiar with them you'll find there's tremendous flexibility available to you.